# Steps to install py2cairo?

Tags: python, cairo, easy-install, pip, pycairo

Seems that pycairo was branched to py2cairo for 2.x versions back in May. There are no pip or easy_install installation options for py2cairo. I've grabbed the latest py2cairo tar, as well as the cairo 1.8.10 package which is registered as a dependency. When I try to configure cairo first, it errors out at the end that it needs pkg-config. However, I also can't find a pkg-config install option in pip or easy_install. I'm at a complete loss as to how to get py2cairo installed. I'm doing this on Mac Snow Leopard.

Comment: I use homebrew instead of macports. I found cairo in the available formulae in brew, so I'm installing that now. Took care of pkg-config too. If this goes, then I'll try another manual install py2cairo. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pkg-config is a helper tool used when compiling applications and libraries.

If you are using macports then the package name is pkgconfig.

```
port install pkgconfig
```

See the portfile at : http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/pkgconfig/Portfile

The details are at : http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/FrontPage